# Elment over a sticky navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to build a website and I have a sticky navigation bar (place in the header). I added a new section and place there some text, but when I scroll down, it surpasses the navbar as you can see: [image]

Is there any option to avoid it?

HTML code:

```css
.about-text 
{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0 ,0);
    /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
            <div class="about-text">
                <h2>Hey there!</h2>
                <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am Tsahi Barshavsky</h1>
                <p>Thanks for steping by</p>
                <button id="aboutBtn" onclick="window.location.href='#about';">More on me</button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have  z-index: 2;, and didn't show your nav-bar CSS and I guess it is lower (or none), set your nav-bar z index to higher value.  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp And for future reference post code that is relevant to question, in this one for example you are mentioning navigation and there is no HTML or CSS for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your `navbar` has `position: fixed` and also a `z-index` set to a value higher than your `about-text`

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

.about-text {
    z-index: 2;
}
```